# What are the pre-requisites for debugging Android platform classes?

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging

For every *platform* installed by the SDK Manager, the SDK contains a file called **android.jar** which contains stub implementations of each dependency.

For example, here is part of the decompiled output for **android.app.Activity.java**

```
public void startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int requestCode) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
}
```

This satisfies compilation requirements, but the actual code for execution is provided by the firmware at run-time.

Contrast this with the support library (or 'androidx.') classes which are actually compiled into the APK.

In the latter case, when instruction-stepping, the *debugger* has no difficulty in highlighting the actual source code being executed because, by definition, the matching source was readily available to the IDE that built the app.

But for the platform classes; **Question 1**: Is it therefore impossible for the *debugger* to give sensible results unless the IDE built the app using the exact same sources with which the device firmware was built?

And does it follow; **Question 2**: If this requirement is not met (for example when attempting to debug an app built via api-29 but running on an api-24 device) that the *debugger* message ...

```
Source code does not match the bytecode
```

... is normal, expected and unavoidable behaviour?